# How to expand tan(x+y) as normal form?

Tags: trigonometry, expression-manipulation

```
TrigExpand@Tan[x + y]
```

gives

$\frac{\sin (x) \cos (y)}{\cos (x) \cos (y)-\sin (x) \sin (y)}+\frac{\cos (x) \sin(y)}{\cos (x) \cos (y)-\sin (x) \sin (y)}$

but I expected

$\frac{\tan (x)+\tan (y)}{1-\tan (x) \tan (y)}$

Evaluating `TrigExpand` with arguments $\tan (x-y)$ or $\tan (3*x)$ also returns results in terms of sine and cosine. What should I do to get results in terms of the tangent?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to induce *Mathematica* to simplify to `Tan` functions is to introduce the arguments as inverse tangents, as in $x\equiv \arctan a$ and  $y\equiv \arctan b$. Then you could write for example

```
Simplify[
  TrigExpand@Tan[ArcTan[a] + ArcTan[b]]] /. {a -> Tan[x], b -> Tan[y]}

(* ==> (Tan[x] + Tan[y])/(1 - Tan[x] Tan[y]) *)
```

or more generally with an expression containing `x` and `y`:

```
expr = Tan[3 x];

Simplify[TrigExpand[
   expr /. {x -> ArcTan[a], y -> ArcTan[b]}]] /. {a -> Tan[x], 
  b -> Tan[y]}

(* ==> (Tan[x] (-3 + Tan[x]^2))/(-1 + 3 Tan[x]^2) *)
```

**Edit**

Referring to the answer by @belisarius, I thought it's worth pointing out that you can achieve similar flexibility with my approach. For example, if you want the expression simplified in terms of `Sin` instead of `Tan`, just use inverse sines where I said to use inverse tangents above:

```
Simplify[TrigExpand[
      expr /. {x -> ArcSin[a], y -> ArcSin[b]}]] /. {a -> Sin[x], 
    b -> Sin[y]}

(*
==> (Sin[x] (-3 + 4 Sin[x]^2))/(Sqrt[
 1 - Sin[x]^2] (-1 + 4 Sin[x]^2))
*)
```

The insertion of the inverse function causes `Simplify` to see the expression as more complex until it reaches a form in terms of the inverse variables. When the simplification is done,  we revert the variables back without invoking `Simplify` again.

You can try this with any target function that has an inverse.

Answer (score 6):

You may use this function I wrote for transforming more general trig expressions:

```
trigSet[exp_, inTerm_] := 
 Module[{trigSyms, rels, set, setRep, setRep1, toLow, oneInTermsOf, 
                                                        allInTermsOf, fq, ruleAll, convert},
  trigSyms = {Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot, Sec, Csc};
  rels     = {csc sin == 1, cos^2 + sin^2 == 1, 1 == cos sec, tan == sin/cos, cot tan == 1};
  set      = ToExpression /@ ToLowerCase /@ SymbolName /@ trigSyms;
  setRep   = Thread[set -> (ToExpression /@ (StringJoin[#, "[x_]"] & /@ ToString /@ set))];
  setRep1  = Thread[set -> (ToExpression /@ (StringJoin[#, "[x]"] & /@  ToString /@ set))];
  toLow    = Thread[trigSyms -> set];

  oneInTermsOf[one_, of_] := Solve[rels, {one}, Complement[set, {one, of}]];
  allInTermsOf[of_]       := Flatten[oneInTermsOf[#, of] & /@ Complement[set, {of}]];
  fq[x_, y_]              := FreeQ[x, Alternatives @@ Complement[set, {y}]];
  ruleAll[of_] := Rule @@@ Transpose[{#[[1]] /. setRep, #[[2]] /. setRep1} &@
                                                     Transpose@(List @@@ allInTermsOf[of])];
  convert[expr_, inTerms_] := FullSimplify@ Union@Select[
        Flatten@NestWhile[# /. (List /@ ruleAll[inTerms]) &, {TrigExpand[expr] /. toLow }, 
                              ! Or @@ (fq[#, inTerms] & /@ Flatten@#) &], fq[#, inTerms] &];
  HoldForm[ Evaluate@convert[exp, inTerm]] /. (Reverse /@ toLow)
  ]
```

Use it this way:

```
trigSet[Tan[x + y], tan]
(*
 {(Tan[x]+Tan[y])/(-1+Tan[x] Tan[y]),(Tan[x]+Tan[y])/(1-Tan[x] Tan[y])}
*)
```

You can also try

```
trigSet[Tan[x + y], sin]
```

to get the result in terms of `Sin[]`, etc

```
trigSet[Tan[3 x], tan]
(*
 ((Tan[x] (-3+Tan[x]^2))/(-1+3 Tan[x]^2))
*)
```

or

```
trigSet[Tan[x - y], tan]
(*
 -> {(Tan[x]+Tan[y])/(-1+Tan[x] Tan[y]),(Tan[x]+Tan[y])/(1-Tan[x] Tan[y])}
*)
```

**Edit**

Usually those trig expressions have more than one form depending on the signs of the involved square roots.

For example:

```
s = Cos[x] Sin[x]; (*The function to match*)
s0 = ReleaseHold@trigSet[s, sin](*the candidates*)
(*
{-Sin[x] Sqrt[1 - Sin[x]^2], Sin[x] Sqrt[1 - Sin[x]^2]}
*)
```

If you want to build up the piecewise function you could do something like:

```
s1 = FullSimplify[Reduce[# == s, x, Reals] & /@ s0] ; (*the validity domains*)
hh[x_] := Piecewise[Transpose@{s0, ReplaceAll[#, ((xx : Element[u__, __]) && z__) -> 
                                       Hold@Resolve[Exists[u, xx, z], Reals]] & /@ s1}]
```